# Using $(this) on multiple class selectors in Jquery

Tags: jquery

In this code, I have a main element (.long-brick2), and other elements that are inside it's div (.round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2). I have a function that changes the colour of all those elements when the user hovers over them:

```
$(".long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2").animate({
    backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
});

$(".long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2").mouseleave(function() {
   $(".long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2").animate({
     backgroundColor: "#85A0DD"}, "slow");
});
```

This code works, but of course, it changes the colours of all the elements with those class names, all over the page. how can I use $(this) to achieve targetting the element I'm hovering over?

```
$(".long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2").mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).animate({
     backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
});
```

This code successfully targets only the element I'm currently hovering over, but it doesn't target (.round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2), it only binds $(this) to (.long-brick2). So how can I target them all?

***Edit***

Got the desired effect with:

```
$(".long-brick2").mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).children().animate({
      backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
       $(this).animate({
         backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
               });
```

Comment: Your second example should work fine. Note that it only fires `animate()` on the element that raised the event, not necessarily just `.long-brick2`

Comment: How to explain it, my second example only changes the color of the element where the cursos is, meaning it changes the color of (.long-brick2) but it ignores (.round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2)...If I hover over say (.round2) the color changes, but then (.long-brick2) is ignored so it doesn't work as intended...I would like to achieve something like ($this, $this, $this, $this, $this) which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: A working example of the problem would be much better than a verbose description

Answer (score 1):

The `mouseenter` event should pass an event parameter into the function which would contain a reference (eg `.target`) to the element that triggered the event.

Although, as @rory-mccrossan points out, `$(this)` should work fine too...

Alternatively, could you not use CSS with `:hover` pseudo-class? Does this styling need to be JS? Or is background colour change just an example for debugging?

SASS:

```
.long-brick2, .round2, .round2-2, .round2-2-2, .round2-2-2-2 {
  background-color: #2699F2;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #85A0DD;
  }
}
```

(pick a library to have animation/transition mixins - I know bootstrap supports them via SASS).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".long-brick2").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).children().animate({
   backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
    $(this).animate({
     backgroundColor:"#2699F2" }, "slow");
           });
```

This did it.